# How to play a video with the YouTube API using YouTubePlayerFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to play video in my Fragment. However, I cannot get it to work. If I'm extending 'YoutubeFailureRecovery' I get:

> 09-06 21:56:40.472: E/AndroidRuntime(4946): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

This is my .xml:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And this is the class:

```
public class YoutubeFragment extends YoutubeFailureRecovery {

    YouTubePlayer player;
    YouTubePlayerView playerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailview, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.player);
        playerView.initialize(DataHolder.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    }

    @Override
    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return playerView;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class YoutubeFailureRecovery extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
```

I just don't know what to do. I tried to extend my Fragment class with 'YoutubePlayerSupportFragment', tried to add a video-like fragment in XML, but nothing is working (error inflating). Maybe someone has some experience with using YouTube API in Fragment?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> The YouTubePlayerView only works with an Activity that **extends**
>   YouTubeBaseActivity.

If you want to use Fragments **you have to use the YoutubePlayerFragment** / SupportFragment.

You can for example create your custom Fragment that inherits from YoutubePlayerSupportFragment:

```
public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    public VideoFragment() { }

    public static VideoFragment newInstance(String url) {

        VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("url", url);

        f.setArguments(b);
        f.init();

        return f;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize("yourapikey", new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) { 
                    player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In code it could look like this:

```
VideoFragment f = VideoFragment.newInstance("your-video-url");   
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
```

The "**fragment_container**" in this case should be an empty **FrameLayout**.

Comment: @Philipp, I am having a similar issue here, http://goo.gl/V55wsu .  I would appreciate any advice you have.

Comment: When I rotate the screen the video just dissapears. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks this helped me but how can i make this fragment to use full parent view

Comment: @Phipipp You are a Genius

Comment: Still works in 2016!! :D the google sample doesn't really help. Thank you so much

Comment: Can we display 2 video in the same activity with this solution? I mean for example:
VideoFragment f = VideoFragment.newInstance("url");   
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit()
VideoFragment f2 = VideoFragment.newInstance("url2l");   
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f2).commit()

Comment: url didn't work for me. I had to use "videoId" in place of the URL