# YouTubeFragmentPlayer Android App - Only Black Box appearing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am trying to build sample Android app in which the main activity contains a YouTubePlayerFragment.  I get no errors with my implementation, but when I run this app on an AVD or my phone, the fragment for the YouTubePlayerFragment is just a black box.  No video loads.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

**YouTubeFragment.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;

public class YouTubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static YouTubeFragment newInstance() {
        YouTubeFragment fragment = new YouTubeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    private void init(){
        initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    public YouTubeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        YouTubeFragment ytf = newInstance();
        ytf.init();
        //inside fragment use getFragmentManager instead of getFragmentSupportManager
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.youTubePlayer, ytf)
                .commit();


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And your developer key/Google API console configuration is setup correctly?

Comment: Yes, just checked this by using my key in a sample application from Google's documentation, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I have a working version of this (problems with target SDK 21, using 19):

**YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments2;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;


public class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            String errorMessage = "custom ERror MessAgE";
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.youtube_fragment);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create a newInstance(). The instance is created in your xml. And when you are in onCreateView that is a specific instance already.
So you should be able to replace these lines

```
YouTubeFragment ytf = newInstance();
ytf.init();
```

With

```
this.init();
```

Or more simply

```
init();
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Tried it, but still having the same problem.

Comment: Does the device have version 4.2.16 or later of the YouTube app?

Comment: Yes, I have the YouTube 6.0.11 apk installed on the AVD.  Also have the same issue on phone (Nexus 5) which is running Lollipop.

Comment: Have you checked out this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664934/how-to-play-a-video-with-the-youtube-api-using-youtubeplayerfragment

By the looks of it the main differences they have from yours is that you don't need to override onCreateView() and they add the fragment afterwords. As in replace it with a framelayout in the xml and do a getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()            .add(R.id.youTubePlayer, ytf).commit(); in the main activity

Comment: Have moved my code around to match the example you referenced.  Moved the creation/initialization of the fragment to the main activity in the onCreate().  Also using an empty FrameLayout in the main activity XML  Now getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a()' on a null object reference`.