# Embedding a Youtube video in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am embedding a Youtube video in my Android app. I have been reading several blog, posts, etc. and I am a little bit lost. My layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".UD1">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerView"
        android:layout_width="715dp"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The activity that I have created is:

```
public class UD1 extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    String APIkey = "aavvss";
    String video1 = "hjFaqDNUVFo";
    String video2 = "41cJ0mqWses";
    String video3 = "uT8-YdXPNBk";
    String video4 = "vSdAv931s-g";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ud1);
        final YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
        playVideo(video1, youtubePlayerView);

    }

    public void playVideo(final String videoId, YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView) {
        //initialize youtube player view
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(APIkey,new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
}
```

}

When I run the application I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

Full stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: es.elena.learninggame, PID: 8501
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.elena.learninggame/es.elena.learninggame.UD1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:438)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3326)
    at es.elena.learninggame.UD1.onCreate(UD1.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source:19)
```

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.(Unknown Source:1)
            ... 28 more

However, my activity already extends **YouTubeBaseActivity**. As said, I have read several blogs, including StackOverflow and I didn't solve the error. Could please anyone guide me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Youtube Initialization is not happening properly in your Activity. Change your activity like this.

```
public class UD1 extends YouTubeBaseActivityextends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String APIkey = "aassvv";
    String video1 = "hjFaqDNUVFo";
    String video2 = "41cJ0mqWses";
    String video3 = "uT8-YdXPNBk";
    String video4 = "vSdAv931s-g";

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ud1);
        final YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
        // Initializing your video player like this
        youtubePlayerView.initialize(APIkey, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,  errorReason.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            player.loadVideo(video1);

            // Hiding player controls
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(APIkey, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jose Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks!!! I have just tried, but again, the same Exception. I have copied full stacktrace in the original post

Comment: Okay, let me just see, I have already implemented this and it works fine

Comment: Did you download the latest .jar file from here - https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: Yes, this afternoon indeed :(

Comment: Okay.  Can you follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665554/5773044

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have looked at that post and I have tried to implement it. To be honest I am new in Android (perhaps the question will be "stupid"), but when I create the VideoFragment f and I try to set the parameters (f.setArguments(b);), AndroidStudio says the method does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solutions has been easier. In the layout, I was using a theme

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

Well, by removing the theme, Youtube player loads perfectly.